# Dependency Injection just for Base Activity crashes child activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a BaseActivity which is extended by multiple Activities. I have a requirement to inject an object(InputProvider.java) in BaseActivity but it is not required in it's child activities.

```
@Subcomponent
public interface BaseActivityInjector extends AndroidInjector<BaseActivity> {
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<BaseActivity> {}
}

@Module(
  includes = {
    AppModule.class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
    InitializerModule.class},
  subcomponents = {
     BaseActivityInjector.class
  })
public abstract class AppInjectionModule {
  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ActivityKey(BaseActivity.class)
  abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindBaseActivityInjectorFactory(BaseActivityInjector.Builder builder);
}

@Module
public class InitializerModule {
  @Provides
  public InputProvider getInputProvider() {
    return new InputProviderImpl();
  }
}

public abstract class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Inject
InputProvider inputProvider;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Once I run my app, it crashes on very first screen(splash screen), which also extends BaseActivity, with following message:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.app.mobile.android.dev/com.app.mobile.android.SplashScreen}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for
>   Class. Injector factories were
>   bound for supertypes of com.delta.mobile.android.SplashScreen:
>   [com.app.mobile.android.uikit.view.BaseActivity]. Did you mean to
>   bind an injector factory for the subtype?

The error log points to `AndroidInjection.inject(this);` in BaseActivity via SplashScreen.

Answer (score 1):

`AndroidInjection` looks up the right component for your Activity by type. If you try to inject `SplashScreen` and it can't find a component registered for `SplashScreen` then it will throw an exception.

If you only want to inject `BaseActivity` but not the children then you can't use `AndroidInjection` for this. You will have to create the component on your own and inject your Activity that way.

Alternatively you can not extend BaseActivity, or declare a component for *every* Activity and use AndroidInjection as it is intended. If you inject the child activity it will also inject the fields in the parent.

Comment: Going with the a base module for BaseActivity and multiple components for every Activity, do you know how to refer to the activity in the base module?fun providesPackageManager( activity: BaseActivity ) : PackageManager = activity.packageManager. If this is provided in BaseModule, dagger can't find BaseActivity and being base module, i can't provide a specific activity instance.

Comment: @Vairavan the current (only) option is to bind every Child as the Base type in a module (or the component builder...in which case you can't use dagger.android either) There [was an idea about adding a way to bind types](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/961#issuecomment-378608908) with dagger.android, but I don't think this will be implemented any time soon

Comment: Thanks, binding concrete to base type does it, works like a charm :-)